# Swift: How to parse and decode JSON containing an array of dictionaries

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse the JSON at a certain API endpoint using the Codable protocol in Swift. **How do you properly decode this?**

So far, I've created a Model struct to represent the `Post` objects located at the endpoint. I'm also using JSONDecoder() to decode the array of Post objects. I've tried restructuring my Model to have nested structs but that doesn't work.

Here's a sample of the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "content": "Content 1"
    ...
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "title": "Title 2",
    "content": "Content 2"
    ...
  }
]
```

Here's the Model:

```
struct Post: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, content: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case title, content
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the fetching code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, _, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error: Failed to fetch data from url. [\(error.localizedDescription)]")
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data not available.")
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let posts = try decoder.decode([Post].self, from: data)
                print("POSTS: : ", posts)
                // ^ THIS IS NOT WORKING. I've tried Post.self too.

            } catch let jsonError {
                //error
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:
`ERROR:  keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "ID", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"ID\", intValue: nil) (\"ID\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Look at the JSON. It seems one of the dictionaries (not shown in your question) doesn't have an `ID`.

Comment: Is this the real JSON? Because there clearly **is** a value at index 0 for key `ID`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy - I checked the full JSON and ALL of the dictionaries have an ID. Even when I put "title" or "content" above/before "ID" in the struct, it would yield the same error for that key ("title" or "content"), even though they exist/are not nil.

Comment: @vadian This is part of the full/real JSON. I took out the other keys because I only need to use the "ID", "title", and "content" keys/fields of the dictionaries.

Comment: The given JSON matches the structs and is supposed to be decoded without errors.

Comment: Well the error clearly states that the `ID` is _nil_ , but if you say so, you can make your structure properties _optional_. You would get rid of that error but I don't think that will fix the problem as the value will still be nil

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi correct. I've already tried making the properties Optional, but still got nil values. I think the concern is with the hierarchy of the JSON - at the top-level. it's an opening array bracket and then within it are the dictionary braces enclosing each Post object. In other words, it seems to be an array of Post dictionary objects. However, there are no keys; there are just blocks of Post objects. So I think it's trying to look for an "ID" key at the top-level but there is none - it's within the dictionary object. So how do I decode this?

Comment: I don't think that will be a problem because `[Post].self` will take care of that. IMO, what it will do is , it will see that you have passed `[Post]` so it will take the _first index_ and try to convert it to the Post model and since all the model(or struct) keys match with that of JSON, there shouldn't be an error , but there is !

Comment: Paste the json response in an online validation tool to see what you get and/or use https://quicktype.io/ to generate a swift struct for you and check if it differs from what you have

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted my question without reason. 
Thanks @JoakimDanielson - but I've already used quicktype.io and checked I had the same Swift struct it generated for me :)

Comment: you have written let id instead of let ID in the structure. The automatic mapping during decoding does take this into account.

Comment: @DarkInnocence my CodeyKeys enum takes care of this with `case id = "ID"`. I found the real issue which had to do with the complicated URL. The rest of the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. You just need to check your json data. This error shows in the case:

- When certain key in `Coding keys` doesn't match with the key of `json` data. In your case it is clearly = `"ID"`

  > To solve this check response in `postMan` and make the keys exactly same in   `Codingkeys`